# Weighted Search and Sort Python

Tags: python, sorting, search, artificial-intelligence

I am creating a creature simulator in python, and the first thing I am doing is to search for food. Naturally one of the things to search by is distance, but I also want to sort by quality of the food source. Is there a good way to do this? I figured I'd get a list of all possible sources and then sort the list and I know python has built in sort functions but I don't really understand the lambda part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda (you don't have to use a lambda, you can use a named function) is where you plug in your utility calculation.  Create a function that assigns a score to a food source based on distance and quality first, and then pass that in as the "key" to your sort function to sort a list based on it.  The important thing is that you can express your utility calculation as a function that produces a sortable output (like a numerical score) -- if you can't, then you don't have anything to sort by.

As an example, a straightforward utility function would be to score based on quality minus distance:

```
sources.sort(key=lambda source: source.quality - source.distance, reverse=true)
```

`reverse=true` is because this function assigns a higher score to better options; you're free to invert your utility method ('distance minus quality') and leave it out.  `source.distance` will of course have to be replaced with some sort of function to calculate the distance relative to the current location.

Comment: Thank you very much. I assume that source will relate to sources like in a for source in sources, as it key=lambda knows to just iterate over source?

Comment: Yes, "source" is the name of the argument for the lambda just like it would be were it `def utility_function(source)` on a separate line.  And the sort function passes a single item of the sortable collection into the key function at a time, as the first argument, and the key function produces a value (usually a number).  The sort function then uses those produced values to sort the collection.